# Display latest comments for post if available if not show na

Tags: mysql

i have two table post table and comment table,where for a particular post there could be comments or there will not be.

Am using the following query statement:

```
SELECT id, Post, finaltable.comments FROM table-1 INNER JOIN ( SELECT comments, ticket_id FROM table-2 INNER JOIN 
( SELECT MAX(id) latest_comment_id FROM table-2 GROUP BY ticket_id) latestcomments ON table-2.id = latestcomments.latest_comment_id ) finaltable ON finaltable.ticket_id = table-1.id
```

This displays the post with the latest comments,but if there are no comments for a post it is not displaying the post at all.Only post with comments are displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a LEFT JOIN

```
SELECT id, Post,
       CASE WHEN finaltable.comments is null then 'NA' else finaltable.comments end as comments
FROM table-1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT comments, ticket_id 
                 FROM table-2
                 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) latest_comment_id
                             FROM table-2  
                             GROUP BY ticket_id) latestcomments
                  ON table-2.id = latestcomments.latest_comment_id ) finaltable
 ON finaltable.ticket_id = table-1.id
```